# How to extract all data having same class using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

i need to find all title data and stock number. I wrote a code and its works well with single item when I use find_all method it shows en error please have a ook at my code and guide me how can I handle this. thank you!

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as
import csv

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup
def get_detail_page(soup):
     title = soup.find_all('div',class_="vehicle-location-name mts bold",id=False).text
     print(title)
     stock = soup.find_all('div',class_="text-lightgray",id=False).find('span').text
     print(stock)
def main():
    url = "https://www.superbrightleds.com/vehicle/2002-acura-cl-vehicle-led-lights?make=1&model=554&year=2002"
    get_detail_page(get_page(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the error that it shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def get_detail_page(soup):
    titles = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "vehicle-location-name mts bold"})
    stocks = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "text-lightgray"})

    title = [title.get_text() for title in titles if title]
    stock = [stock.get_text() for stock in stocks if stock and 'Stock #' in str(stock)]

    for idx in range(len(stock)):
        print(f'{title[idx]}\n\t{stock[idx]}')
```

Comment: @a clue thank you but it shows some values more than 1 time. could you please fix this too?

Comment: I've edited my original post; instead of looping through every single div instance, you can apply ```findAll()``` to just the ```div``` classes you're interested in

Comment: than you so much bro for your help but if you don't mind please if you see output it shows  title with the others stock no, not the exact of that title has

Comment: and could you please store the output into csv file?

Comment: To write to csv library, use the ```csv``` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html (see examples on the page linked)